# magento related product tab on admin panel not visible

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, adminhtml

in my magento Product Information page on admin panel .related product link not visible.
I try reindexing clear cache and basic thing to fix this but no results.
I haven't any idea why this happen.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check if that module's output is disabled or not from backend.
From `System > Configuration > Current Configuration Scope > Advanced > Advanced > Disable Module Output`.

Comment: yes it disabled but after enable it and reindex not work

Comment: Please enable it and check again